# How to parse json file in terraform

Tags: terraform

There's a JSON file.

```
 {
   "Qa" : [
      "Name":"qa1" 
],
   "Dev" : [
      "Name":"dev1"
]}
```

I need to parse this json file in terraform.

Please help me on this.
So if you select workspace as qa the contents of Qa should be list.

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: Hi Shubham - welcome to stackoverflow.  As @M0nst3R commented, this is not valid json ... the brackets s/b braces.  Then see answer below from Martin Atkins.  Also, to improve your question, please provide the terraform code you tried and the result from that code.

Answer (score 1):

To decode JSON data into a data structure in Terraform you'd use [the `jsondecode` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsondecode).

The result of that function will be a Terraform language value of a type decided based on the correspondence between JSON types and Terraform types listed in the documentation for the function.

This function requires valid JSON syntax as input, so you will first need to make sure that the system or person producing this JSON generates a valid JSON document.

Comment: I have added jsondecode function like this. In locals block.jsonfile=jsondecode("a.json).then Name = [for p in local.jsonfile.Qa[*] : p.Name].But in place of .Qa there should some dynamic name.suppose if workspace qa is selected then contents of Qa from json file only should be list.please assist me on this.